# discord.js - remove a specific role from all members

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to remove a role in my guild from many people. Yet, not everyone in the guild has that role, and there is a **large** number of them.

```js
message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
  member.roles.remove("12345678901234");
});
```

This code works, but it is not efficient. The above code is very slow. Do you have a better code? Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would delete the role and then create it again.

```js
const role = message.guild.roles.cache.get("RoleID");
message.guild.roles.create({
data: {
name: role.name,
color: role.color,
hoist: role.hoist,
position: role.position,
permissions: role.permissions,
mentionable: role.mentionable
}
})
role.delete('I had to.')
```

It works very quickly, much faster than manually grabbing each member and removing the role, especially with a big server.

Answer (score 5):

```js
const Role = message.guild.roles.cache.get("RoleID");
Role.members.forEach((member, i) => { // Looping through the members of Role.
    setTimeout(() => {
        member.roles.remove(Role); // Removing the Role.
    }, i * 1000);
});
```

---

I assume your code is slow because of Discord's API limits. You have no delays in your code, which means your code will be executed immediately.

The code I provided will remove a role from a member every 1 one second.

If you want to remove the role immediately, you need to delete it. It will be removed from everyone.

Comment: You could tell by his question that isn't what he meant. He is looping through a huge guild, so it's understandable that it's taking forever. And you literally just made it much much slower.

Comment: @MakeHellTal Discord has a [rate limit](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits#header-format). Trying to bypass this limit will pause requests until a certain number of seconds passed. A forEach loop is running faster than Discord's API limits, which will cause Discord to pause the requests.